# How to make a script that doesn't ask permission every time it's opened

Tags: applescript, macos-mojave, system-preferences

I have made an apple script that takes pictures of people using PhotoBooth. However, every time I open it, it asks for permission to use PhotoBooth instead of instantly taking a photo. I have already set the [Security & Privacy > Privacy > Automation > Allow Script to use PhotoBooth] but it still prompts me every time to allow PhotoBooth. Is there any way to fix this without downloading anything or changing my script? Thanks!

Comment: how did you set  [Security & Privacy > Privacy > Automation > Allow Script to use PhotoBooth] ? I am working in an app, which uses, appleScript, but it doesn't work in Mojave. its not a sandboxed app, & i have also added "NSAppleEventsUsageDescription" in .plist file, but still i am not able to get the permission popup itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your script saved as an applet? While 10.14 remembers previous user-granted permissions, it will re-prompt every time the script changes. Traditional AppleScript applets implement a basic persistence mechanism that saves the current state of the script's top-level variables upon quitting. Discussion here:

https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/mojave-and-applescript-applets/1563/13

One quick trick for avoiding any persistent state:

```
script MyScript
    -- original code goes here…
end script

on run
    local tempScript
    copy MyScript to tempScript
    run tempScript
end run
```

If you do need to save state (e.g. user preferences) between runs, then you'll either need to code sign the applet or else use an alternate mechanism (e.g. `NSUserDefaults` via AppleScript-ObjC).

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked first try. I didn't need any save states so the code worked first try :)